# Is there a way to schedule Cloud Shell commands in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to schedule some of my BigQuery table load commands that I execute in the Cloud Shell CLI. How can I schedule my CLI commands in Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: 1) Should you do this? See @Chris32's answer. 2) Can you do this? Yes, you can use ssh to execute remote commands on Cloud Shell. I wrote a program in Golang that has an extensive interface for interacting with Cloud Shell remotely: https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go 3) Also review https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/cloud-shell/ssh 4) I would use Cloud Run and Cloud Scheduler. Build a container with your commands wrapped in a REST interface, deploy to Cloud Run and schedule as you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Shell isn't a tool intended to use as part of your production environment, you should take a look into it's [terms and conditions](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations). you might find this part especially blocking for this purpose:

> Non-interactive sessions will be ended automatically after a warning.
>   Note that Cloud Shell sessions are capped at 12 hours, after which
>   sessions are automatically terminated.

What you can actually do is to create a Cloud Function and trigger it by a cron job or use a Compute Engine instance and [schedule a command on linux](https://study.com/academy/lesson/using-scheduling-commands-in-linux.html)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to shell jobs, like a HTTP trigger.
2. Create a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) container running the commands you want on HTTP trigger. Here is an [example](https://github.com/sethvargo/cloud-run-bash-example).

This solution is serverless, only runs when it's triggered. Cloud Run allows 2M request for free. Cloud Scheduler allows 3 jobs per month per account free, then Cost/job/month $0.10.